# No error message for Radio Buttons when using jquery validate

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

I've got a few radio buttons:

```
<div><label><input type="radio" name="Impression" value="Excellent"> Excellent</label></div>
<div><label><input type="radio" name="Impression" value="Good"> Good</label></div>
<div><label><input type="radio" name="Impression" value="Poor"> Poor</label></div>
```

And then...

```
$("#RegisterForm").validate({
    rules: 
        {
           'Impression': { required: true }
        }
    });
```

The `required` works in the sense that the user can't submit the form, and it will scroll the user back to these buttons if one is not selected. But unlike all other input options in this form (text and drop downs), no error message is displayed for the radio buttons.

Comment: It's working for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/dzg9f1kr/  ~ Inspect your DOM

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the error label:

```
<label for="Impression" class="error">Please select an impression.</label>
```

jQuery validate doesn't know what to show when there's a problem with the validation.

[Example from jQuery.validate's documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method/#example:-makes-the-gender-radio-buttons-required)

EDIT: To make the label hidden, just don't include content for it. The label is meant to be an instructional message for the user until validation fails, at which point it becomes the validation failure message.

http://jsfiddle.net/1k3zfqxq/

Comment: You absolutely do not need to create a `label` element for this.  The plugin handles it automatically:  http://jsfiddle.net/gj7vc2mr/

Comment: @Sparky, that's what I thought too.  The plugin DOES handle it for all the other types on inputs, but it doesn't seem to be working for Radio Buttons.

Comment: @J. Tutus -- how would you make the error label hidden unless validation fails on the radio buttons?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston, I suspect that the error message label is inserted into your other `label` resulting in invalid HTML or some other problem with your DOM layout.  You'll need to create a demo so we can know for sure.  Otherwise, I can see it working:  http://jsfiddle.net/dzg9f1kr/

Comment: Fix the broken HTML or layout issues rather than creating an error label where such is not needed.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston http://jsfiddle.net/1k3zfqxq/ - You don't need to specify label content. It looks like the element just needs to exist.

Comment: Clearly it does not need to exist at all:  http://jsfiddle.net/dzg9f1kr/

Comment: @Sparky Look at the difference in the output after submitting the forms in both fiddles. I assume this is either a bug in jQuery.validate, or just a poorly defined feature.

Comment: It's not a bug.  The `label` is dynamically created and inserted *after* the input.  In the case of a group of radio elements, it is inserted after the *first* radio in the group.  It's normally handled as per my answer.  I think the OP's particular HTML layout is simply covering it, but it's still there.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create any error elements in advance.

I simply think you have a problem with your DOM layout where the default error message is being covered over by some other elements in your design.  Since we can't see your DOM, we can't know exactly how to fix it.  However, you can inspect your particular DOM and figure out an exact solution based on my generic example below.

By default, the error message is a `label` element and it's dynamically inserted *after* the input element.  In the case of a `radio` or `checkbox`, it's inserted after the *first* element in the radio group.  You can use the `errorPlacement` option to conditionally place this message elsewhere.

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if (element.attr("type") == "radio") {
        error.insertBefore(element.parents('div')); // place it before the radio group
    } else {
        error.insertAfter(element);  // default placement
    }
}
```

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/jktLyLgy/